# What is a good data-structure for doing pair-key lookup in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures, key, lookup

By *pair-key* I mean two keys as a pair mapped to a single value.

F.ex I could use a set of strings as keys, and i could search by iterating, though I’m wondering it there’s a better way to structure the data and find pairs based on either one of or both the keys.

```py
d = {
    {"a", "b"}: "a-b relationship",
    {"c", "d"}: "c-d relationship",
    {"e", "f"}: "e-f relationship"
}

# single key
query = "a"
match = [v for k, v in d.items() if query in k]

# both keys
query = {"a", "b"}
match = [v for k, v in d.items() if query == k]
```

Comment: What about you make a custom class implementing `__getitem__` or the like? I'll make an example implementation.

Comment: `{('a', 'b'): '...', ...}`?

Comment: @iteratedwalls This won't make a set hashable. OP should just use a tuple

Comment: As a side note - don't use `dict` as name.

Comment: @DeepSpace a tuple wouldn't be symmetric `('a', 'b') != ('b', 'a')`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest version would be just using [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) as keys:

```py
my_dict = {
    frozenset({"a", "b"}): "a-b relationship",
    frozenset({"c", "d"}): "c-d relationship",
    frozenset({"e", "f"}): "e-f relationship"
}

# both keys
my_dict[frozenset({"a", "b"})]
'a-b relationship'

# single key
[v for k, v in my_dict.items() if "a" in k]
['a-b relationship']
```

But you may also want to try making your own `dict`-like class with [`collections.abc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.MutableMapping):

```py
import collections.abc as abc

class pair_dict(abc.MutableMapping):

    def __init__(self):
        self._pairs = {}
        self._singles = {}
        super().__init__()

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, abc.Iterable) and not isinstance(key, str):
            return self._pairs[frozenset(key)]
        return set(self._singles[key].values())

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if isinstance(key, abc.Iterable) and not isinstance(key, str):
            key = frozenset(key)
            self._pairs[key] = value
            for k in key:
                self._singles.setdefault(k, {})[key] = value
        else:
            raise ValueError('key must be an iterable, not just a string')

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, abc.Iterable) and not isinstance(key, str):
            key = frozenset(key)
            del self._pairs[key]
            for k in key:
                del self._singles.setdefault(k, {})[key]
        else:
            raise ValueError('key must be an iterable, not just a string')

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._pairs)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._pairs)
```

You can then use your class for both purposes:

```py
d = pair_dict()
d[('a', 'b')] = 'AB'
d[('b', 'c')] = 'BC'
d[('a', 'c')] = 'AC'

list(d.items())
[(frozenset({'a', 'b'}), 'AB'),
 (frozenset({'b', 'c'}), 'BC'),
 (frozenset({'a', 'c'}), 'AC')]

d[('a', 'b')]
'AB'

d['a']
{'AB', 'AC'}
```

`collections.abc` has a list of which methods you have to override for each abstract base class (abc) it provides [near the top of the documentation linked above](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes).

You'll also want to add other convenience methods like `__repr__` and/or `__str__` if you use this as a public-facing class.

Note: I used a separate internal `dict` and `dict` of `dict` for pairs and single references. That makes single lookups much faster, but at the cost of a small extra memory use and making item setting a little slower. Adjust to your use case. =)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion, writing your `addKeyPair` function to override the behaviour of `d[(a, b)] = v`.

```py
def addKeyPair(d, a, b, v):
    d[(a,b)] = v
    d[(b,a)] = v
    d.setdefault(a, []).append(v)
    d.setdefault(b, []).append(v)

d = {}
for a,b in ('ab', 'bc', 'ca'):
    addKeyPair(d, a, b, a+b)

print(d)
# {('a', 'b'): 'ab', ('b', 'a'): 'ab', 'a': ['ab', 'ca'],
#  'b': ['ab', 'bc'], ('b', 'c'): 'bc', ('c', 'b'): 'bc',
#  'c': ['bc', 'ca'], ('c', 'a'): 'ca', ('a', 'c'): 'ca'}

print(d[('a', 'b')])
# ab

print(d[('b', 'a')])
# ab

print(d['a'])
# ['ab', 'ca']
```